# Component gradient vectors of a function span normal space of submanifold

Tags: orthogonality, submanifold

I am struggling with part of a proof about the normal space of a submanifold. The text states:

> Lemma: Suppose $M = f^{-1}(q) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ is an $n$-dimensional
> submanifold. Then for the normal space of $M$ at $p$ we have $N_p M = span \{grad f_1(p),...,grad f_k(p)\}$.

The proof starts like this:

> Proof: To exhibit $N_p M$, regard the matrix product $J_f \cdot v$ as a
> scalar product with the rows of the Jacobian:
>
> \begin{equation*} J_f \cdot v=  \begin{pmatrix} (grad f_1)^T \\
> \vdots \\
> (grad f_k)^T  \end{pmatrix}
> \cdot v =
> \begin{pmatrix} \langle grad f_1,v \rangle \\
> \vdots \\
> \langle grad f_k,v \rangle \end{pmatrix}
> \end{equation*}

Choosing for $v$ one of the gradient vectors grad $f_i$ results in a nonzero product, that is
$span \{grad f_1(p),...,grad f_k(p)\} \perp$ ker $J_f(p)$. In general, $Y \perp X$ implies $Y \subset X^{\perp}$. Therefore, in our case,

$span \{grad f_1(p),...,grad f_k(p)\} \subset (ker \ J_f)^{\perp} = (T_p M)^{\perp} = N_p M$.

But both sides are $k$-dimensional vector spaces, and so the spaces must be equal.

The definition of a submanifold I am using is:

> Definition: A non-empty subset $M \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ is called
> an $n$-dimensional $C^{\alpha}$-submanifold if $M = f^{-1}(q)$ where
> $f \in C^{\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^{n+k},\mathbb{R}^{k})$ has $q \in
> \mathbb{R}^{k}$ as a regular value, and $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now I understand that if $v=f_i$ for some $i$, then $J_f \cdot v \neq 0$ since $J_f$ has rank $k$ which means that the rows of $J_f$ are all non-zero. This means that the $i$th row of $J_f \cdot v$ is $\|grad f_i\| \neq 0$. However, I don't see why this implies that $span \{f_1(p),...,f_k(p)\}$ is orthogonal to the kernel. Of course, from the observation above we know that none of the $f_i$ is an element of the kernel though.

What am I missing here? I feel like this is something easy. Appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The tangent vectors $u$ are precisely those for which $J_f(p)u = 0$. So $(\nabla f_i)\cdot u=J_fu=0$.

Comment: @Chrystomath Thanks for your comment. The fact that the tangent space is the kernel of the Jacobian/differential was proven prior to the lemma given above, but I do not see how this helps me with my problem. Also I do not understand your last equation. Is $(\nabla f_i)$ supposed to be the matrix with the component gradient functions as its rows? Otherwise I think the equation does not make sense.

Comment: As I have stated above I understand that the vector $J_f \cdot v$ for $v=grad f_i$ is non-zero, and thus the component gradient vectors $grad f_i$ are not in the kerel of $f$, but how do we know that all of them are in fact orthogonal to the tangent space/kernel?

Comment: For any tangent vector $u$, $J_fu=0$, so any row of $J_f$ gives $grad f_i\cdot u=0$, for *all* i and *all* u.

Comment: @Chrystomath Oh sure, I got your point now. Thanks for clarifying. $grad f_i$ is orthogonal to any vector in the tangent space, so any vector in the span of $grad f_1,...,grad f_k$ is also orthogonal to the tangent space. But what is the point of the statement: "Choosing for $v$ one of the gradient vectors $grad f_i$ results in a nonzero product", then? Sorry if I am missing the point completely.

Comment: It's not clear from what you wrote, but I think it's to show that they are linearly independent and so form a basis. Otherwise, $\sum_ia_i(grad f_i)=0$, so $a^TJ_f=0$, but this can't be true by feeding in $v_i=grad f_i$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have edited my post to include the rest of the proof. In fact, we really need the fact that the span is $k$-dimensional. But this is true by assumption since $J_f$ has rank $k$.